# Custom Views or Custom Cells

Tags: objective-c

I have a question about creating custom views. I wanted to implement an interface where I want to have different objects configured in one place, each of them with it's own controls. Kind of like in automator, on the right side view where the workflow is shown with different actions. Are those NSView or NSCell subclasses ?
Any example will be appreciated !

Ken

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can tell an NSCell and an NSView apart:

NSCells are basically stamps. Given a certain value/object, the NSCell knows how to draw that on the screen how you want it. Like NSTextCells know how to draw NSString's on the screen how you want them. NSCells don't have state, don't remember anything, they're just a one-shot set of drawing instructions that get executed with a given value/object. The idea is to reuse NSCells as much as possible to make drawing things on the screen super simple.

NSViews are sort of logical containers for what goes on on your screen. They can technically do their own drawing, but quite a few of them use NSCells to do their drawing. For example, NSTextField uses an NSTextCell to draw it's text on the screen, it also contains the extra logic necessary to toggle between editing and not-editing by displaying the text box you can type in during editing and using the NSTextCell when you're not editing. NSViews are also part of the responder chain and can respond to mouse-clicks, keyboard events, and the sort.

You're probably going to end up with both, NSViews to hold all the controls you want to use to configure each object and NSCells to draw custom UI elements (like if you use non-standard controls).